# Average distance to circle in a plane

Tags: trigonometry, average

[image]

In the picture, imagine this grid of circles extends infinitely. I would like to calculate the average distance of any point outside a circle to the nearest circle. I simplified this the average distance of any point in the red plane to the blue circle. My attempt goes like this:

distance to circle $= r-R$, then

$$ \text{avg} = \frac{\iint(r*(r-R))dr \, d\phi}{\iint(r)d\phi \, dr} \quad \text{with} \quad 0<\phi < \frac{\pi}4 \quad \text{and} \quad R<r<\frac{X}{\cos(\phi)}$$

with $R$ the radius of the blue circle, and $X$ the right vertical boundary of the red plane. As $x = r\cos(\phi)$, hence $r=\frac{x}{\cos(\phi)}$. Integrating to $r$ this gives:

$$ \text{avg} = \frac{\int(\frac13 r^3 - R\frac12 r^2) d\phi}{\int\frac12 r^2d\phi} \quad \text{with}  \quad R<r<\frac{X}{\cos(\phi)}$$

which becomes

$$ \text{avg} = \frac{\int \left[ \frac13 \left( \frac{X}{\cos(\phi)} \right)^3 - R \frac12 \left( \frac{X}{\cos(\phi)} \right)^2 - \left( \frac13 R^3 - \frac12R^3\right ) \right]\, d\phi}{\int(\frac12\left[ \frac{X}{\cos(\phi)})^2-\frac{1}{2}R^2 \right] \, d\phi} \quad \text{with} \quad 0<\phi<\frac{\pi}{4}$$

with a little help from wolfram alpha I get:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \left( \frac{X}{\cos(\phi)} \right)^3 \, d\phi = \frac{1}{2}X^3 \left( \sqrt2+2~\tanh^{-1}( \tan(\frac{\pi}{8}) \right) ~,$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \left( \frac{X}{\cos(\phi)} \right)^2 \,d\phi = X^2$$

hence

$$ \text{avg} = \frac{\frac13 \frac12 (X^3  (\sqrt 2 + 2 \tanh^{-1}( \tan(\frac{\pi}{8})) -\frac12 R X^2+\frac{1}{3}R^3}{\frac12 (X^2-\frac14 \pi R^2)}$$

I calculates some values this for some values of $R=1$ and $X$ in excel, results plotted in the $2^{nd}$ graph. The value goes up as $X/R$ approaches $~1~$ (?!). This cannot be correct.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: "the average distance of any point outside a circle": this is unbounded, you are not telling us everything.

Comment: i hope it is clear now

Comment: Instead of writing stuff like "with $0<\phi<\pi/4$" all over the place, it would be helpful to attach the boundary values to the integral signs like this: $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}$, encoded by `$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}$`. As things are written right now, you are literally saying that $\frac\pi4= \frac{1}{2}X^3(\sqrt2+2~\tanh^{-1}(\tan(\frac{\pi}{8}))$, which of course is not what you meant to say.

Comment: ok, done, thanks

Comment: I believe the error is in the numerator: The part of the integrand that is constant with respect is $-\frac13 R^3 + \frac12 R^3$, which after integrating yields $-\frac{\pi}{12} R^3 + \frac{\pi}8 R^3$, not $-\frac12 R*X^2 + \frac13 R^3$ as you have written.

Comment: I guess you are using variable $R$ and $X$ to check that the answer makes sense.  Okay, but why not set $R=1$ to begin with?  Also, I'd suggest making $X$ the horizontal distance so that $1<r<X\cos{\phi}$ which should make for easier integrals.  Personally, I'd just set $X=\frac32$ to begin with.

Comment: Wait sorry I made an error in my previous comment (the term $-\frac12 R*X^2$ is correct and comes from the $-\frac12 \frac{X^2}{\cos\phi}$), but still you did not do the $-\frac13 R^3 + \frac12 R^3$ correctly.

Answer (score 2):

WLOG we have a unit circle and a square of side $s$ (presumably your $\frac XR$).

The area is given by the integral
$$\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/4}\int_{r=1}^{r\cos\phi=s}r\,dr\,d\phi=\frac12\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/4}\left(\frac{s^2}{\cos^2\phi}-1\right)\,d\phi=\frac12\left.\left(s^2\tan\phi-\phi\right)\right|_0^{\pi/4}=\frac{s^2}2-\frac\pi8.$$

This result is obviously correct.

Now for the distance,

$$\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/4}\int_{r=1}^{r\cos\phi=s}(r-1)r\,dr\,d\phi=\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/4}\left(\frac{s^3}{3\cos^3\phi}-\frac{s^2}{2\cos^2\phi}+\frac16\right)\,d\phi\\
=\left.\left(\frac{s^3}3F(\phi)-\frac{s^2}2\tan\phi+\frac\phi6\right)\right|_0^{\pi/4}=\frac{as^3}3-\frac{s^2}2+\frac\pi{24}$$

where (by Alpha) $a=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}+\text{artanh}\left(\tan\dfrac\pi8\right)=1.14779357469631\cdots$.

The ratio is a smooth, quasi-linear function:

[image]

Comment: thanks ! I found my error

Comment: @DavidK: right. This is fixed, hoping there are no more errors.